# JQuery scroll event freezes page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, viewport

I setup a trigger which checks if an element is in the viewport (visible on the screen) and added it to the scroll event. This works fine on some pages, but large pages it freezes the page. On firefox I can't scroll at all, it crashes the page completely and an alert comes up telling me that jquery is not responding. Heres the trigger:

```
 $(window).on("scroll", function () {
     $('div').each(function () {
         if ($(this).isOnScreen(true)) {
             $(this).trigger('report.appear');
         }
     });
 });
```

and heres the isOnScreen function (which finds out what elements are in the viewport):

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function () {
     var win = $(window);
     var viewport = {
         top: win.scrollTop(),
         left: win.scrollLeft()
     };
     viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
     viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

     var bounds = this.offset();
     bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
     bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

     return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
 };
```

It doesn't matter how many div elements are on the page, it seems to be just large amounts of any content that crashes it, or at least large HTML tables that I have. Is there another way to detect when an element appears  on the screen without using the scroll event? Or is there a way to use scroll without crashing jquery?

UPDATE:

When I comment out this:

```
 $(window).on("scroll", function () {
     $('div').each(function () {
         /*
        if ($(this).isOnScreen(true)) {
            $(this).trigger('report.appear');
        }
        */
     });
 });
```

it works fine, so its the isOnScreen function thats causing the problem. Is there a better way to do this which won't overload the browser like this?

Answer (score 2):

[MDN: scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll):

> Since scroll events can fire at a high rate, the event handler shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM modifications. Instead, it is recommended to throttle the event using requestAnimationFrame, setTimeout or customEvent, as follows:

```
;(function() {
    var throttle = function(type, name, obj) {
        obj = obj || window;
        var running = false;
        var func = function() {
            if (running) { return; }
            running = true;
            requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name));
                running = false;
            });
        };
        obj.addEventListener(type, func);
    };

    /* init - you can init any event */
    throttle ("scroll", "optimizedScroll");
})();

// handle event
window.addEventListener("optimizedScroll", function() {
    console.log("Resource conscious scroll callback!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, throttle function, thats exactly what I need to do. I'm not sure how to use that function though, how I control the fire rate with it.

Comment: @JohnSlotsky you will maybe need to make it compatible for older browser, beside that, you can use the code as it is, and then just listen to the  `optimizedScroll`  event in jQuery instead of `scroll` [hashchange answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33776583/1960455)

Answer (score 0):

I have written a plugin specifically for this: [jQuery.isInView](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.isinview). It is designed to handle large numbers of elements, and large numbers of calls. (And it is tested for that.) That should do the job for you.

That aside, you definitely [should throttle the scroll event](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/). Even if browsers don't brick, you'll suck their battery dry on mobile. If you want to use an existing, proven solution, I'd suggest [`_.throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) in the [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library. Ben Alman also has an established [`$.throttle`](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) on offer. The [MDN code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll#Example), as posted in the answer of @t.niese, will certainly do the job as well.